# How to walk an iterator by list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> b = ["q","r","f","v","d","a"]
>>> c = zip(a,b)
>>> list(c)
[(1, 'q'), (2, 'r'), (3, 'f'), (4, 'v'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'a')]
>>> [x for x in list(c)]
[]
```

Why does the comprehension not work? I want to do some computations with the elements and store them in a new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) creates an iterator that can only be used once.

If you use it to construct the `list(c)`, there are no more items in the iterator that could be used for the list comprehension.

If you skip the call to `list(c)`, your list comprehension works perfectly fine.

You can also see that by looking at the individual steps of the iterator:

```
In [60]: c = zip(a, b)

In [61]: c.__next__()
Out[61]: (1, 'q')

In [62]: c.__next__()
Out[62]: (2, 'r')

In [63]: c.__next__()
Out[63]: (3, 'f')

In [64]: c.__next__()
Out[64]: (4, 'v')

In [65]: c.__next__()
Out[65]: (5, 'd')

In [66]: c.__next__()
Out[66]: (6, 'a')

In [67]: c.__next__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-bc609abc99c4> in <module>()
----> 1 c.__next__()

StopIteration:
```

If you use the list comprehension right away, you get the desired result:

```
In [68]: c = zip(a, b)

In [69]: mylist = [x for x in list(c)]

In [70]: mylist
Out[70]: [(1, 'q'), (2, 'r'), (3, 'f'), (4, 'v'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'a')]
```